# Adding lemongrass to soup: sliced or bashed?

Tags: soup, herbs

I want to cook lemongrass into a soup that doesn't normally ask for it because I like the way it tastes. So I have to adjust the recipe on my own vs following one. I did some research about how it is usually incorporated and it seems that two general methods exist: slicing and bashing. Since slicing seems much easier, I was wondering if there are some other benefits to bashing it, like to get more flavor out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Peel the outer layer or two off a stalk. Cut the top, less desirable portion off.  You will likely be left with 5 or 6 inches of prepared lemongrass.  Give the bottom two or three inches a good smash with the flat side of your chef knife.  Toss it in the soup pot.

The problem with slicing is that you will have lots of small inedible/tough pieces of lemongrass stalk in your soup.  With my suggestion, you can remove the stalk prior to eating.  If you want more flavor, use more than one stalk.

Comment: this is exactly the same conclusion i arrived to the hard way